# How to test state changed over setTimeout?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

How do I verify (Jest / Enzyme) that state is changed, at least 2 times, where there is a use of setTimeout?
Lets say I have this simplified code:

```
const [testTimeout, setTestTimeout] = useState<number>(0);

useEffect(() => {
   setTimeout(() => setTestTimeout((new Date()).getTime()), 5000);
}, [testTimeout]);

<label id='testedValue'> {testTimeout} </label>
```

How do I skip the timeout to check updated value?
Many thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "skipping the timeout"? If I understand it correctly, you can add an optional prop which you'd pass only in a testing scenario, controlling the useEffect (i.e. de-activating it after a few updates).

Comment: My wish is to test the value in '#testedValue' and to test it again as if the setTimeout elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use the enzyme's `done`, like so:

```
it('test with setTimeout()', (done) => {

        const component = mount(
            <MyComponent />
        );

        const label = component.find('#testedValue');

        expect(label.textContent).toEqual(0);

        setTimeout(function () {
            expect(label.textContent).toEqual(666);
            
            done();
        }, 6000);
    });
```